# What does the "kz" abbreviation mean in a programming/technical context?

Tags: translation, technical-terminology

I am a non-German-speaking programmer writing software that interfaces with a database that uses German field names. There are a number of these fields that are prefixed with `KZ_`.

The only translation I can find when I look it up is [Konzentrationslager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_concentration_camps), but given the context, this doesn't make sense.

Here is a subset of fields containing `KZ` if it helps:

```
BEST_KZ
DRUCK_KZ
FAKT_KZ1
FI_KZ_STEUER
HAUPT_KZ
KANTEN_KZ
KZ_BESTELL
KZ_BESTELLUNG
KZ_EK_GESAMT
KZ_GESPERRT
KZ_IGNORE
KZ_KOSTENLOS
KZ_MAHNSPERRE
KZ_MASSEINH
KZ_MODELL
KZ_PARTNERVERTRIEB
KZ_SPRACH
KZ_STEUERFLAG
POS_KZ
TEXT_KZ
TRANSFER_KZ
WIEDERVORLAGE_KZ
ZAHL_FB_KZ
```

Comment: Did you ask the people who wrote the code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would actually rather translate it to ***Kennziffer*** which would mean *indicator* or *index number* in English. Especially with the examples you mentioned, *Kennzeichen* doesn't make any sense to me – even though the actual meanings are pretty close.

So `BEST_KZ` for example would probably stand for "Bestell-Kennziffer" and would then be a running number identifying a single order.

If those fields you listed were named in English I would expect them to have an `_ID` added – like `ORDER_ID` for `BEST_KZ`, for example.

See also http://www.dict.cc/?s=kennziffer

**Update**: Just to give an impression of some "Kennziffern" in their bureaucratic habitat:

a) some [job descriptions at University of the Arts in Berlin](http://www.udk-berlin.de/sites/content/themen/aktuelles/stellenausschreibungen/index_ger.html):

- "Fakultät Gestaltung | Fakultätsverwaltung | Kennziffer 2/1441/14 "
- "Zentrale Universitätsverwaltung | Referat für Studienangelegenheiten | Kennziffer 1440/14"

b) a form that enables you to ask for a "Kennziffer" ("Antrag auf Erteilung/Änderung einer Kennziffer für Antragsteller") at justiz.bayern.de – [here's the PDF](http://www.justiz.bayern.de/imperia/md/content/stmj_internet/gerichte/amtsgerichte/coburgzema/antrag_auf_erteilung_einer_kennziffer.pdf) (check page 2!)

…but of course it could also mean "Kennzahl" or "Kennzeichen" or "Kurzzeichen" or whatever the engineer/programmer had in mind. The meaning in each of these is very similar –– however being a German part-time programmer myself I have to point out that I actually find the short form "_KZ" quite disturbing and personally would **never ever** use it – but instead **always** stick to "_ID".

Comment: Eine Ziffer ist ein (einzelnes!) Zeichen aus der Menge {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. Es gibt also genau zehn verschiedene Ziffern. Daher kann ein Feld, dass korrekterweise als »Kennziffer« bezeichnet werden darf, nur einen dieser zehn verschiedenen Werte annehmen. Wenn ein Feld länger als 1 Byte ist oder andere Zeichen als diese zehn Ziffern enthalten darf, dann ist »Kennziffer« eine unzulässige Bezeichnung. »Kennzeichen« ist passender.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I think you are underestimating the liberties bureaucrats take with language. Google "Kennziffer" and (past the dictionary results) you will find that, for example in Gerichtsdeutsch, a _Kennziffer_ can have arbitrary many, erm, _Ziffern_.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wenn man es etymologisch auf die Spitze treibt, stammt Ziffer von *cifra* und das bezeichnet ausschließlich die Null :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: eigentlich von صفر _ṣifr_ (Null)

Comment: Statt Kenziffer kann genauso gut Kennzshl gelten. Aber darüber sollte die Programmbeschreibung Auskunft geben.

Answer (score 7):

In a programming context, this most likely stands for *[Kennzeichen](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/kennzeichen),* which translates to *[flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_field), feature,* or *characteristic.*

Comment: While Kennzeichen technically means all these things, it makes less sense than _Kennziffer_ in most fields given above. I also think the word is most often used to mean _(car) number plate_ (also KFZ-Kennzeichen).